# Node.js unhandled "error" event

Tags: node.js

This error randomly appears When leaving my discord bot online for too long, around 3-4 hours but sometimes the error occurs sooner and sometimes later. It's really bothering me.

```
  events.js:188
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Unhandled "error" event. ([object Object])
    at Client.emit (events.js:186:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.onError (D:\BasementMonster\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
    at WebSocket.onError (D:\BasementMonster\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:128:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at _receiver.cleanup (D:\BasementMonster\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:211:14)
    at Receiver.cleanup (D:\BasementMonster\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:557:13)
    at WebSocket.finalize (D:\BasementMonster\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:206:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Comment: We are going to need more information than this. What have you done to debug your code or research the problem? HAve you reduced this to a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, I've researched the "unhandled event errors" and most of them aren't caused by the code I don't think. This error isn't new, at all - It has happened since I started coding a discord bot. I CAN start from scratch and see if it still appears, and I'll probably do that tomorrow.

Comment: By not telling us what you have already tried you have made it unlikely that anyone wants to dig into this. How have you proven those other hints are not related? What other steps have you taken to solve this? Since we don't have any code that you say reproduces this problem it's impossible to say what could be wrong. node has a pretty comprehensive debugger. Have you tried this? Added any logging? narrowed the problem down to a specific chunk of code?

Comment: Basically, your job is to find out if this is a problem in the code, or a problem in the environment. Maybe the code can be more resilient to environment problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrestled with this problem for a while in my own code. The main problem is that the trace is completely unhelpful, *and* that the error occurs so infrequently as to make "run it in the terminal and wait" a futile task. Eventually, I was able to figure out that the Discord.js client itself was throwing an error -- this wasn't mentioned in any of the documentation I read, so I had no handler for it -- and since this oopsie happens in the Discord.js package itself, there was no line in my code for it to point to in the trace.

What needs to exist in the code somewhere is something along the lines of

```
client.on('error', (err) => {
   console.log(err.message)
});
```

This is adjusted, of course, for whatever your Client object is, and whatever you want the error handling to be.
This specific trace, as far as I can tell, comes from losing Internet connection, which is something I want to have a record of, so instead of console.log() I called my own custom function that writes the event out to a logfile with a timestamp.

Testing this by running an instance of the bot and killing my Internet connection revealed that not only did the logging function work, but that Discord.js automatically restored the bot's session after it came back. (Your mileage may vary.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an error handling event, like this:`client.on('error', console.error);`