# DiscordJS and Linux's Screen

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm facing an issue with discordjs and i don't understand it. I run "node main.js" into a linux screen, detach it, go to sleep and when i come back, it crashed. Could you enlight me ?

```
    # screen -r BotApex
(node:6559) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
events.js:180
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ([object Object])
    at Client.emit (events.js:178:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.onError (/root/ApexLegendsSnipeBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:374:17)
    at WebSocket.onError (/root/ApexLegendsSnipeBot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:128:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at _receiver.cleanup (/root/ApexLegendsSnipeBot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:211:14)
    at Receiver.cleanup (/root/ApexLegendsSnipeBot/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:557:13)
    at WebSocket.finalize (/root/ApexLegendsSnipeBot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:206:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js unhandled "error" event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531293/node-js-unhandled-error-event)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your bot ran into an `error` event while you were away. If you don't handle error events they usually make your bot crash. To prevent the bot from crashing, simply add an error listener:

```js
client.on("error", info => {
  console.log('Error event:\n' + JSON.stringify(info));
  // handle the error here
});
```

Please keep in mind that the error event has been called for some reason and that you should handle the error afterwards.